# How to use Mysql If function to evaluate a datetime column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to evaluate using a php mysqli prepared statement on whether an expiration datetime column is more than equal to the `Now()` date time, before returning the users name in the name column.
But I am getting an incorrect result with php where when the `expire_date` is 2019-09-27 01:00:00 and the `Now()` is 2019-09-26 23:58:02 I get false.  What is strange I get the desired result when I type the query in the terminal.

Using just Sql queries:

```
mysql> SELECT IF(Now()<=expire_date, for_user, 'false') FROM forgottenleafttokens WHERE(for_user='herm' AND pass_token='9c3d5eee11f1c7cacdf676b46df87bccb650783d66afc62aee2b7f6e9382aade4ca4e1840896f788b4cff4342b4dec0842f3c577f5f61bf17fd538c7f34ca69a');
+-------------------------------------------+
| IF(Now()<=expire_date, for_user, 'false') |
+-------------------------------------------+
| herm                                      |
+-------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Using php:

```
            $query = "SELECT IF(Now()<=expire_date, for_user, 'false') FROM forgottenleafttokens WHERE(for_user=? AND pass_token=?)";
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('ss', $us_er, $tok_en);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt->bind_result($user);
            $result = "";
            if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                    $result = $user;

                } return $result;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

Can someone please give pointers on what is wrong with my php prepared statement that I am using with the Sql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What timezone is the mysql server setup to run in and what is the type of the expire_date? If it is TIMESTAMP, it is adjusting for the timezone and if it is DATETIME it is not.  I don't see anything wrong in the query, however, the code is a little verbose and not iterating the result set correctly.  I tried to clean it up a little assuming this will only ever return 1 or 0 results. Ex: LIMIT 1;

```
            $result = false;
            if ($stmt->fetch()) {
                $result = $user;
            }
            return $result;
```

If you are indeed having some automagic timezone conversion issues, you can use the `CONVERT_TZ` function to normalize it.

```
SELECT IF(NOW() <= CONVERT_TZ(expire_date, 'UTC', 'America/New_York'), for_user, 'false') ...
```

Comment: @Alex Barker, timezone is system time zone which according to my Linux machine is SAST(Johannesburg, South Africa) and DATETIME is the type.  Thank you, will try cleaning it up.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The clean up solved my problem and yes the return will always be 1 or 0.